# How do i classify a column using predefined class intervals and rank the new column in R?

Tags: r

I have a column in R I would like to classify it based on intervals e.g(0-10,10-20) and rank the classified column. How do I do this in R?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Are you looking for `?cut` or `?findInterval`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `cut()`  for this purpose. With this function you can specify an upper and lower bound on an interval in your case `c(0,10, 20)` as well as the specified labels `c("0-10","10-20" )`. This also has an ordered option which would allow you to sort the column using the specified groups.

```r
Df %>%
    cut(col = colname, breaks = c(0,10, 20), labs = c("0-10","10-20" ), ordered_result =T) %>%
    arrange(colname)
```